# How to get unique values in a row in bash (with awk?)

Tags: bash, awk, unique

My dataset looks like

```
A B A
B C A B
D E A D
A D B
```

And I like to get for each row unique values sorted:

```
A B
A B C
A D E
A B D
```

which are then counted (tab separated):

```
A 4
B 3
C 1
D 2
E 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I am bored right now:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; OFS="\t"}
      { delete row; s=""
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) row[$i]
        for (e in row) {
            s= s ? s OFS e : e
            total[e]++
        }
        print s     
       }
    END{ for (e in total) print e, total[e] }' file
```

Prints:

```
A   B
A   B   C
A   D   E
A   B   D
A   4
B   3
C   1
D   2
E   1
```